# Function not working jQuery. Need it to overwrite

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need if `yes2 == none` to remove `.bottomandroid` and instead, to display `.cta` but it's not doing it. How can I please get this to work?

```
else if (isAndroid) {
  $('.apple').remove(); 
  $('.android').show();
  $('.cta').remove();
  $('.bottomcta').remove();  
  $('.bottomandroid').show();
  $('.bottomapple').remove();

  $(window).load(function() {
    if ($('.yes2').css('display') == 'none') {
      $('#button').css('display', 'block');
      $('#bottombadge > p').remove();
      $('#badge > p').remove(); 
      $('.bottomandroid').remove();    
      $('.cta').show(); 
    }
  });  
}
```

How can I overwrite `.cta` over `.bottomandroid`? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$('.cta').bind();
      $('.bottomcta').bind();`  makes no sense

Comment: I think you should use `.show()` instead of `.bind()`

Comment: You should really be using CSS for all of these operations... Like `@media` for Mobile/Desktop views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.apple, .bottomcta, .bottomandroid, .bottomapple, .cta').hide(); 
$('.android').show();

$(window).load(function() {
  if ($('.yes2').css('display') == 'none') {
    $('#bottombadge > p, #badge > p, .bottomandroid').hide();
    $('#button, .cta, .bottomcta').show();
  }
});
```

The problem is that you should use `hide()` instead of `remove()` and `show()` instead of `bind()`

Comment: Thanks Mahesh. It sort of works, but bottomadroid still appears at the underneath bottomcta

   else if (isAndroid){
                
            $('.apple, .bottomcta, .bottomapple, .cta, .cta2').hide(); 
   $('.android, .bottomandroid').show();

   $(window).load(function() {
    if ($('.yes2').css('display') == 'none') {
      $('#bottombadge > p, #badge > p, .bottomandroid, .android').hide();
      $('#button, .cta, .bottomcta').show();
     }
   });
            }

Comment: class name is `bottomadroid` or `bottomandroid`? You can add class name which you want to hide inside this `$('.apple, .bottomcta, .bottomandroid, .bottomapple, .cta').hide(); `

Comment: it's bottomandroid . Since I changed to show and hide, it doesn't work properly as the .hide is prioritised over show :(

Comment: Please update second line from `$('.android, .bottomandroid').show();` to `$('.android').show();` and let me know if it works then i will update the answer as well

Comment: I have this at the bottom of the page as well, maybe this is it? 

    $(window).load(function() {
        if ($('.yes').css('display') == 'none') {
            $('#button').css('display', 'block');
        }
    });

    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (y > 300) {
            $('#bottombadge').fadeIn();
            $('.bottomcta').fadeIn();
            $('.bottomandroid').fadeIn();
            $('.bottomapple').fadeIn();

Comment: if (($('.yes,.yes2').css('display') == 'none')) {
                /* (y > 300) AND (display IS "none") */
                $('#bottombutton').fadeIn(); 
                
            } else {
                /* (y > 300) AND (display ISN'T "none") */
                $('#bottombutton').fadeOut();
            }
            
            
        } else {
            $('#bottombadge').fadeOut();
            $('.bottomcta').fadeOut();
            $('.bottomandroid').fadeOut();
            $('.bottomapple').fadeOut();
            $('#bottombutton').fadeOut();
        }
    });

Comment: It looks good, Kindly mark this answer as useful so that it helps others as well

Comment: there's still an android appearing at the bottom under .cta . Any ideas how to remove it please?

Comment: please add new class to your bottom element which is still appearing something like `.bottomAndroid` and add this class with `.hide()` function

Comment: $('.bottomandroid, .bottomapple').hide();  if I add this, it also hides .bottomapple on iOS which I don't want if else if (($('.yes2').css('display') == 'none')) {

Comment: you have condition as `else if (isAndroid) {` then how this code is working for iOS?

Comment: I have an if statement similar to Android for iOS

Comment: Okay, so you need to change code for android like `$('.bottomandroid').hide();` and for iOS like `$('.bottomapple').hide();`. So it will only hide android bottom in android and ios bottom in iOS